# How to write method that returns hash set of common string

Tags: java, set, hashset

How do you create a new hash set that combines common string values (case sensitive) from two other sets?

The main method contains:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
    set1.add("blue");
    set1.add("red");
    set1.add("yellow");
    set2.add("blue");
    set2.add("red");
    set2.add("orange");
}
```

The method header is:

```
 public static Set<String> buildList (Set<String>set1, Set<String>set2){
 set<String> set3 = new HasSet<String>();
 }
```

Comment: How would you do it? What's the logic behind what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to compare the strings in the two sets, and then add them to the third set, I just am confused on how to write the for loop or while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly then you need to retain common values from both the `HashSet` if yes then Use `set1.retainAll(set2)`

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
        set1.add("blue");
        set1.add("red");
        set1.add("yellow");
        set2.add("blue");
        set2.add("red");
        set2.add("orange");

        set1.retainAll(set2);
        System.out.println(set1);
    }
```

**output:**

```
[red, blue]
```

You can modify buildList method as mentioned below which returns common list of string as result.

```
 public static Set<String> buildList (Set<String>set1, Set<String>set2){
   set1.retainAll(set2);
   return set1;
 }
```

Comment: How can i include that outside of the main method, and add it to a new set? Because that returns a boolean value when I want to return a new Set of Strings

Comment: you can use it like mentioned below.

 public static Set<String> buildList (Set<String>set1, Set<String>set2){
     set1.retainAll(set2);
    return set1;
 }

Comment: But what if I want to add those strings to a new set?

Comment: easiest way is to create a copy as below first
Set<String> set3 = new HashSet<String>(set1);
set3.retainAll(set2);